# How to check if local uncommitted changes already present in remote branch?

Tags: git

Situation is following:

1. There is a web server, set up ages ago, with a home directory that contains 3 items:

- a `deploy` script
- bare git repo
- directory with currently deployed code

2. Main code storage is GitHub, but to actually deploy the changes, a developer has to push changes additionally to the "server" remote.
3. When changes are pushed to the bare repo, a post-receive hook runs the `deploy` script. Which, basically, boils down to `cd ~/app && git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master && restart the service`. There are other commands, of course, but they're tangential to the issue at hand.
4. There are cases, sometimes, when people make changes to the files directly on the server, running scripts, fixing bugs, etc. Those changes then, *usually*, committed to GitHub, and go through CI, PR, and so on, and so forth.
5. Alas, *usually* doesn't mean *always*. Sometimes, when one developer deploys a new release, `git reset --hard origin/master` discards all the local changes made by other developers. And if those "soft-deployed" changes have not been committed yet, they're lost forever.
6. To prevent this, an extra check was added to the deploy script: `git fetch origin; if [[ $(git diff origin/master --stat) != '' ]]; then barf rainbows and abort this; fi`
7. Which now broke the deployment workflow, because a developer would fix stuff on server, verify it works, add those changes to GitHub and then try to deploy them in a (more) proper way. But if he forgot to reset his changes, the check will now prevent him from deploying.
8. Of course, one could ssh to the server and do a hard reset manually before deploying, but to make things worse, multiple developers can have multiple "soft-deployed" changes, which leads to the situation when you have to manually go through all the "soft-deployed" files, and compare them one by one if the changes are already present in master branch. Because sometimes they are, and sometimes they aren't.

I cannot *fundamentally* change any part of this process. I can't change people involved either. Given the circumstances, I would like to change the pre-deploy check (#6): "only abort if there are local changes, that are *not* present in the remote master. If *all* changes that are present locally, are also present in the origin/master, proceed with resetting and the rest of deployment script".

Currently used command `git diff origin/master —stat` includes changes that are "incoming", so that is off the table, I think.

One of the options I've considered is to iterate through the changed files and check them one-by-one against origin/master, but that's slow and cumbersome.

Is there a better way, the git way, that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

This is not bullet-proof but it will avoid that you *lose* those changes.... do this instead

```
cd blah
git stash save "saving changes so we do not lose them"
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
git stash pop
restart
```

And the problem now is that you might get a conflict when doing `git stash pop`.... also, you should consider checking if the tree is clean *before* doing `git stash save` (which would mean that `git stash pop` should also be avoided if the tree was clean, of course), but that is just a deviation from the main recipe.

So, at least that should get you close to solving the problem.... but the *real* way to deal with this is to get those changes in **properly** instead of doing stuff on the live environment.